# RegEx to capture same word only when it stands alone

Tags: regex

I trying to use RegEx to capture the same word only when it appears alone (no compound) in a string that separates items with commas.

Example:  `Word,Word with Another,Word,ConcatWord`

Match needed:  `"Word", "Word"` - no comma

I have some limitations in the tool I'm using, so I **can't use lookahead and lookbehind**.

EDIT: It's not possible to select which match group I want to replace, the function can only see the full match.

This RegEx works but captures the comma in the full match:  `(Word)[^\s-]`

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can replace the comma with whitespaces if u don't need comma then apply regrex on it.

Comment: I use the comma to join the remaining elements after replace.

Comment: I have checked ur input string and output on my system,it's capturing  "Word" only. I used findall func.what is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is the comma in the full match

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by, "...I can't select which group in the match I want to extract,..". Please clarify by editing the question.

Comment: There is no comma in the output, check image:https://pasteboard.co/JbMyEa3.png  Please clarify your question exactly what is your problem , share code and output

Comment: it's probably not possible with that requirement as anything you add will by definition have to add another character to the full match.  the only symbol that doesn't add a character to the full match is `\b`, but it matches on any non-word break so you can't 
 exclude space breaks, and the only way to exclude from full match is lookarounds, which isn't supported

Answer (score 1):

As I understand we are given a string and the word `"Word"` and wish to return all instances of `"Word"` that are:

- immediately preceded and followed by a comma;
- are at the beginning of the string and are immediately followed by a comma;
- are at the end of the string and are immediately preceded by a comma; or
- the string is `"Word"`.

You can match the following regular expression.

```
(?:^|,)(Word)(?:,|$)
```

Each instance of `"Word"` that matches is contained in capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/STFaF0/1/)

I would think obtaining matching instances of `"Word"` in the capture group would be of questionable use, as there would be no indication of which instances of `"Word"` in the string they referred to. Potentially more useful would be to save the indices in the string of instances of `"Word"` where there is a match. To do that, however, one must know which language that is being used.

Comment: Thank you, Cary! I can't select which group in the match I want to extract in this tool

Answer (score 0):

I added some regex patterns just try this.
I used

- Positive Lookahead `(?=,)`
- Positive Lookbehind `(?<=,)`
- word boundary `(\b)`

  `/^\bWord(?=,)|(?<=,)\bWord(?=,)|(?<=,)\bWord$/gmi`

Comment: Thank you! I can't use lookahead and lookbehind in this case. Not compatible with this tool